# Generator supply not working on Automatic changeover

Tags: power-supply, switches

I am using [Havells Changeover](http://goo.gl/e6nwKp) for switching between generator and main supply. There are three slots.

- Main
- Gen
- Load

Main has two Neutral wire, Gen has one, but Load has no Neutral wire.

When system is on Main power, it works fine. but when Generator is started i don't get electricity in house.

Lights blinks a little whole time.

Is it due to missing neutral wire in Load?

Should i remove one wire from Main and put in the Load? are all neutral wires same, or there is some difference

Comment: There are _two_ inputs, MAINS and GEN. LOAD is an output. Make a schematic of how you have wired it up as your description is very poor. There is a schematic button on the editor toolbar. Please use capital letters on the start of each sentence as in standard English.

Comment: "Main has two Neutral wire", what for?

Comment: I have improved my question,  electrician combined two neutral wires into main, which i also think  not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR4GqV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. SPN 30 changeover unit wiring.*

Wiring is very straight-forward as shown in Figure 1.

> I have improved my question, electrician combined two neutral wires into main, which i also think not correct.

Ask your electrician why he did this. You haven't supplied a photo or a wiring schematic so any comments would only be guesses.

Comment: Which of neutral wire's other terminal should be connected to ELCB?

Comment: One of neutral wire's one end is connected to ELCB & other to main of device in question. If that is right other wire should go to Load or vice versa.

Comment: How do you think I could possibly give advice based on your description? You are looking at the wires. I can't see them. I don't know where they go. If you'd like to add a schematic as suggested then maybe we can help further.

Answer (score 2):

In the picture you linked, it shows that Main, Generator, and Load each have Line and Neutral terminals.  How do you figure that Main has two Neutral terminals?

Comment: MAIN has only one slot, but in my system it is having two neutral wires.

Comment: Should i remove one neutral wire and put in load?

Comment: You should determine which of the two wires in the Main Neutral terminal really goes to the load, and move it to the Load Neutral terminal (if you move the wrong wire, things probably won't work.)

Comment: So you mean load neutral and main neutral wires are functionally  different?

Comment: From your description, the Main and Load neutrals are apparently not connected other than at this switch, but I can't be sure without examining your wiring.  If the thing does not operate as required, get the electrician who installed it to come back and corrrect his work.

Comment: Your digram gave me clue. I put neutral of electricity vendor's into device main, other neutral into load. Its working fine.